# Redefine short long to use code analysis tools on embedded c code

Tags: c, clang, analytics, mplab

I'm attempting to use SourceTrails (https://www.sourcetrail.com/) to analyze embedded c from the MPLAB CX8 compiler.
It's not entirely trouble-free, as the compiler uses a number of custom features, not found in the C standard.

One of these is the use of `short long` to indicate 24-bit variables in global includes, such as:

```
extern volatile unsigned short long     TBLPTR;
```

SourceTrail (using clang) shows this error: ***cannot combine with previous "short" declaration specifier.***

For the analysis only, I'd like to specify something like on the top of the global include:

```
#define "short long" long
```

but obviously, this fails!

I might have to perform a search and replace, but it would be great if there were a simpler method?

Comment: You already know what actually works: a real macro, or a typedef. *in the headers*, with proper guards. This again is something that is *not* standard C.

Comment: Would it not be smarter to save the current version (either with VCS or make a copy) and then change every `short long` into <whatever>?

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 These are the include files that came with the compiler, so they are not as such part of the project although the compiler relies on them. My current approach is to make a copy of the entire includes folder, use a script to modify the files and then setup a different global includes folder in Sourcetrail, and with this approach I now at about 50 fatal errors, down from about 5000.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like:

```
#define short int
```

`short long` variables will now be `long`, at least in mainstream compilers like `gcc` and `clang`.

Any `short` variables will now be `int`, the side effect is that `short int` declarations will now cause `invalid combination` error.

---

[The solution found by the OP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64240201/redefine-short-long-to-use-code-analysis-tools-on-embedded-c-code/64240307?noredirect=1#comment113660939_64240307) was to use `#define short` which will effectively remove `short` from the type declaration making it `long`.

The side effect is that variables declared `short` will have no type or storage class, and as such, will default to `int`.

In compilers like `clang` or `gcc` the type `int long` will default to `long` effectively making both solutions possible, minding the different side effects.

Comment: This will work for *as `long`* (no pun intended :P) as no one types `short int` anywhere :D

Comment: But they don't want to change the type. `short long` variables should be the type `short long`. This is a non-standard extension that can't be "fixed".

Comment: Yes, @Lundin, unfortunately, I based my answer on the fact that the OP was trying something like  `#ddefine "short long" long`, that of course will also not work, there is no perfect solution for this, as you pointed out.

Comment: @Lundin in that sense a duplicate of the previous [Q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64223961/configure-sourcetrail-to-accept-embedded-c-c-header-files-with-syntax/64224016#64224016)

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I saw this as a different question, albite with the same premiss: The MPLAB compiler.

Comment: I ended up with `#define short`, which effectively changes the 24-bit `short long` into a 32-bit `long`.  Your proposed `#define short int` would change the type into an unsupported `int long` type.

Comment: @fsteff, I'm glad you solved it. I'm not familiar with mplab but in a "normal" c compiler `int long` is exactly the same as `long`, keep in mind that with your solution variables declared `short` will now have no type and will default to `int`. I'll appended this to my answer with context, this may be a good Q&A for future users.

Comment: Thank you. I summarized everything here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64278487/enable-usage-of-modern-code-analysis-tools-on-old-ish-embedded-c-c-code